# jQuery selector performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

Why is id selector faster than class selector in jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fastest selector in jQuery is the ID selector ($('#someid')). This is because it maps directly to a native JavaScript method, getElementById().

Comment: ... and that method is bound to be faster than walking through an array of elements of a certain class.

Answer (score 0):

These points about **Id Selector** may also help You.

**Point 1 :**

**Don't Qualify** your selector when searching by **Id**.

- searching by **Id** uses the browsers native **getElementById** method (which is **very fast**)

**BAD Way**

```
$("div#your-id")
```

**BEST Way**

```
$("#your-id")
```

**Point 2 :**

You should **Always Cache** your Selections **to some variable**

**BAD Way**

```
$("#myList").click( function() {
   $("#myList").hide(); 
});
```

**BEST Way**

```
var myList  = $("#myList");

myList.click( function() {
   myList.hide();  // No need to re-select #myList since we cached it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are able to retrieve elements by Id faster than using a class. Given an Id, one or zero elements are returned when using `getElementById`. This makes it possible for browsers to keep track of the Ids of the elements in a page, providing fast search operations by Id.

Searching by class name makes it necessary to look for all the elements with that given class name. Even though some browsers support `getElementsByClassName`, internally they need to traverse the whole DOM tree to fetch them.

jQuery selector acts as a wrapper around these native functions, together with other such as `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` (and it also comes with a selector library called `Sizzle`, that is used if the browser lacks the necessary native function).

Behavior is not defined if more than one element has this ID.

because ther  references to the DOM elements with a certain ID. In addition, there shouldn